# Question with a review type comment

Tags: php, phpmyadmin

Hey guys, I was wondering if I could get some help with a website I'm building for a project. It is nearly complete but I am struggling with one part, and that is basically comments.

I am creating a movie review site, kind of like IMDB.com but mine is just for class but I'm really struggling with the part I really really want to work.

The ideal situation for me, would to have someone be able to type in what movie they would like to search for, then after they push submit they are brought to another page. On that page the movie information such as Movie Name, Description, Genre, Rating etc... Then underneath that, reviews of what people thought of the movie. But, one thing I CAN'T get is when say someone types in Avatar, movie reviews show up, but when they type in Ghost Rider, the exact same comments show up, I want them to be separate if that makes sense.

For my tables I have,

- **Movie**

  ```
  MovieID, Description, Rating, Genre
  ```
- **Reviews**

  ```
  ReviewID, Name, Review, MovieID
  ```

I'm just at a standstill for this part and it is kind of bugging me, I've looked quite a few places and still haven't been able to find what I'm searching for. 
Here is my code, I regret to inform that I am not very good at PHP or programming for that matter. AND all of this was done in dreamweaver, so if it looks messy, that's why.

```
<?php require_once('../Connections/lesson6.php'); ?>

<?php
//initialize the session
if (!isset($_SESSION)) {
session_start();
}

// ** Logout the current user. **
$logoutAction = $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']."?doLogout=true";
if ((isset($_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'])) && ($_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'] != "")){
$logoutAction .="&". htmlentities($_SERVER['QUERY_STRING']);
}

if ((isset($_GET['doLogout'])) &&($_GET['doLogout']=="true")){
//to fully log out a visitor we need to clear the session varialbles
$_SESSION['MM_Username'] = NULL;
$_SESSION['MM_UserGroup'] = NULL;
$_SESSION['PrevUrl'] = NULL;
unset($_SESSION['MM_Username']);
unset($_SESSION['MM_UserGroup']);
unset($_SESSION['PrevUrl']);

$logoutGoTo = "index.php";
if ($logoutGoTo) {
header("Location: $logoutGoTo");
exit;
}
}
?>
<?php require_once('../Connections/lesson6.php'); ?>
<?php
if (!isset($_SESSION)) {
session_start();
}
$MM_authorizedUsers = "";
$MM_donotCheckaccess = "true";

// *** Restrict Access To Page: Grant or deny access to this page
function isAuthorized($strUsers, $strGroups, $UserName, $UserGroup) { 
// For security, start by assuming the visitor is NOT authorized. 
$isValid = False; 

// When a visitor has logged into this site, the Session variable MM_Username set equal      to their username. 
// Therefore, we know that a user is NOT logged in if that Session variable is blank. 
if (!empty($UserName)) { 
// Besides being logged in, you may restrict access to only certain users based on an    ID established when they login. 
// Parse the strings into arrays. 
$arrUsers = Explode(",", $strUsers); 
$arrGroups = Explode(",", $strGroups); 
if (in_array($UserName, $arrUsers)) { 
  $isValid = true; 
} 
// Or, you may restrict access to only certain users based on their username. 
if (in_array($UserGroup, $arrGroups)) { 
  $isValid = true; 
} 
if (($strUsers == "") && true) { 
  $isValid = true; 
} 
} 
return $isValid; 
}

$MM_restrictGoTo = "login.php";
if (!((isset($_SESSION['MM_Username'])) && (isAuthorized("",$MM_authorizedUsers,      $_SESSION['MM_Username'], $_SESSION['MM_UserGroup'])))) {   
$MM_qsChar = "?";
$MM_referrer = $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];
if (strpos($MM_restrictGoTo, "?")) $MM_qsChar = "&";
if (isset($_SERVER['QUERY_STRING']) && strlen($_SERVER['QUERY_STRING']) > 0) 
$MM_referrer .= "?" . $_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'];
$MM_restrictGoTo = $MM_restrictGoTo. $MM_qsChar . "accesscheck=" .   urlencode($MM_referrer);
header("Location: ". $MM_restrictGoTo); 
exit;
}
?>
<?php
if (!function_exists("GetSQLValueString")) {
function GetSQLValueString($theValue, $theType, $theDefinedValue = "",   $theNotDefinedValue = "") 
{
if (PHP_VERSION < 6) {
$theValue = get_magic_quotes_gpc() ? stripslashes($theValue) : $theValue;
}

$theValue = function_exists("mysql_real_escape_string") ?   mysql_real_escape_string($theValue) : mysql_escape_string($theValue);

switch ($theType) {
case "text":
  $theValue = ($theValue != "") ? "'" . $theValue . "'" : "NULL";
  break;    
case "long":
case "int":
  $theValue = ($theValue != "") ? intval($theValue) : "NULL";
  break;
case "double":
  $theValue = ($theValue != "") ? doubleval($theValue) : "NULL";
  break;
case "date":
  $theValue = ($theValue != "") ? "'" . $theValue . "'" : "NULL";
  break;
case "defined":
  $theValue = ($theValue != "") ? $theDefinedValue : $theNotDefinedValue;
  break;
}
return $theValue;
}
}

if (!function_exists("GetSQLValueString")) {
function GetSQLValueString($theValue, $theType, $theDefinedValue = "",   $theNotDefinedValue = "") 
{
if (PHP_VERSION < 6) {
$theValue = get_magic_quotes_gpc() ? stripslashes($theValue) : $theValue;
}

$theValue = function_exists("mysql_real_escape_string") ?   mysql_real_escape_string($theValue) : mysql_escape_string($theValue);

switch ($theType) {
case "text":
  $theValue = ($theValue != "") ? "'" . $theValue . "'" : "NULL";
  break;    
case "long":
case "int":
  $theValue = ($theValue != "") ? intval($theValue) : "NULL";
  break;
case "double":
  $theValue = ($theValue != "") ? doubleval($theValue) : "NULL";
  break;
case "date":
  $theValue = ($theValue != "") ? "'" . $theValue . "'" : "NULL";
  break;
case "defined":
  $theValue = ($theValue != "") ? $theDefinedValue : $theNotDefinedValue;
  break;
}
return $theValue;
}
}

$colname_GetMovie = "-1";
if (isset($_GET['Search'])) {
$colname_GetMovie = $_GET['Search'];
}
mysql_select_db($database_lesson6, $lesson6);
$query_GetMovie = sprintf("SELECT * FROM movie WHERE MovieName = %s",      GetSQLValueString($colname_GetMovie, "text"));
$GetMovie = mysql_query($query_GetMovie, $lesson6) or die(mysql_error());
$row_GetMovie = mysql_fetch_assoc($GetMovie);
$totalRows_GetMovie = mysql_num_rows($GetMovie);

mysql_select_db($database_lesson6, $lesson6);
$current_MovieID=MovieID;
$query_Recordset1 = "SELECT * FROM reviews WHERE MovieID=$current_MovieID";
$Recordset1 = mysql_query($query_Recordset1, $lesson6) or die(mysql_error());
$row_Recordset1 = mysql_fetch_assoc($Recordset1);
$totalRows_Recordset1 = mysql_num_rows($Recordset1);
?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"   "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Results</title>
<link href="styles/style_sheet.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />



<style type="text/css">
a:link {
color: #0F0;
}
a:visited {
color: #0F0;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<div id="main_container">
<div id="header">

</div><!--End of header-->
<div class="shadow">
<div id="navbar"><a href="index.php">Home</a> &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; <a     href="register.php">Register</a> &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; <a href="login.php">Login</a> / <a href="<?php echo $logoutAction ?>">Logout</a> &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; <a   href="Search.php">Search</a></div><!--End of NavBar-->
</div><!--End of navbar shadow-->
<br />
<div class="shadow">
<div id="Content">
<h2> Results:</h2>
<?php if ($totalRows_GetMovie == 0) { // Show if recordset empty ?>
<form id="form1" name="form1" method="post" action="">
Sorry, there was no movie with that name in the database. Click <a   href="Search.php">here</a> to search again.
</form>
<?php } // Show if recordset empty ?>
<p>&nbsp;</p>
<?php if ($totalRows_GetMovie > 0) { // Show if recordset not empty ?>
<form action="" name="Movie_Search"method="get">
<p>Movie Name: <?php echo $row_GetMovie['MovieName']; ?></p>
<p> Movie Description: <?php echo $row_GetMovie['Description']; ?></p>
<p>Genre: <?php echo $row_GetMovie['Genre']; ?></p>
<p>Rating: <?php echo $row_GetMovie['Rating']; ?></p>
<p>&nbsp;</p>
</form>
<?php } // Show if recordset not empty ?>
<label for="movie_search"></label>
<form action="" method="get">
<center><h2>Reviews</h2></center>
<?php do { ?>
<table width="566">
  <tr>
    <td width="20" height="97"><p><img src="Pictures/Male-User-icon.png" width="67"  height="67" /></p></td>
    <td width="534"><p> <?php echo $row_Recordset1['Name']; ?> says:</p>
      <p><?php echo $row_Recordset1['Review']; ?></p>
      <p>-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------</p></td>
  </tr>
</table>
<?php } while ($row_Recordset1 = mysql_fetch_assoc($Recordset1)); ?>
<p>&nbsp;</p>
<p>&nbsp;</p>
<form id="insert_comments" s style="border:thin" name="insert_comments"   method="POST"first_name">
First Name:</label>
<br />
  <input type="text" name="first_name" id="first_name" />
<br>
  <label for="desc">Comments:<br /></label>
<textarea name="comments" id="comments" cols="45" rows="5"></textarea>
</p>
<p>
<input type="submit" name="submit" id="submit" value="Submit" />
</p>
</form>

<p>&nbsp;</p>
</div>
<!--End of Contentr-->
</div><!--End of content shadow-->

<div class="footer">

<hr />© Nate Christensen<hr />
</div><!--End of footer-->
</div><!--End of Main Container-->


</body>
</html>
<?php
mysql_free_result($GetMovie);

mysql_free_result($Recordset1);

?>
```

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand your question. `SELECT * FROM Reviews WHERE MovieID = $movieid ORDER BY ReviewID DESC` ?

Answer (score 2):

The Reviews table holds the comments, right? I can see that you have a MovieID column in there, so you should be able to query the database with the condition `WHERE MovieID = '$current_movie_id'` to get only comments for a certain movie.

Comment: Yes you're right the review table holds the comments. And that does make sense, the thing is though my class uses dreamweaver and it basically baby's you the entire time so I was trying to do it w/o all of these server behaviors and what not but now it's like way over my head, and If I can post my code somehow it'll be just a jumbled mess. But Gustav that definitely does make sense with the Where clause. But one more quick question how would I declare $current_movie_id?